# GWT FormPanel binding to a Java Class

Tags: gwt

How do I bind a GWT FormPanel to a java object automatically similar to Spring's binding feature?

What I want to accomplish here is have a GWT FormPanel containing input elements. And on form submit bind it to a java class for easy access to the values.

[http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/91316/gwt-formpanel-binding-to-a-java-class]

Answer (score 0):

If by "binding" you mean "on the client-side", then try using the Editor Framework. You can call its flush() from within the FormPanel's onSubmit (you'd have to call edit() when showing the form initially), or simply not use a FormPanel at all and use a button's onClick.

Comment: Yes, I meant client-side. Thanks that is exactly what I was looking for. I guess I have not read documentation since long time. http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiEditors.html

Comment: However, this is complex. I wanted simpler framework that simply binds the form input to a POJO. Reading GWT docs to see if there is a simpler way ...